# DB2 SQL filter/group duplicate columns but with different id's by using the "smallest" id

Tags: sql, db2

if I have a table containing following fields

```
USER_ID  FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE  FAMILY_MEMBER  RELATED_PERSON
1008     '01'                'fatherA'       1002
1008     '01'                'fatherA'       1005
1002     '02'                'motherA'       1005
1004     '02'                'motherB'       1007
...
1005     '03'                'childA'        
1007     '03'                'childB'
```

and now I need to eliminate duplicate related_person rows.
Because the child is already related to the father I don't need to list the relation to the mother anymore.

E.g. for the above example I need to get the following result:

```
USER_ID  RELATED_PERSON
1008     1002
1008     1005
1004     1007
```

What is a smart query to achieve this?

Comment: So its ok for there to be the same user_id (obviously) but the combination of user_id and related_person should be unique?  Is that right or should related_person never appear twice?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. Every family member relationship is in the table but only in one direction, hence there is a father-mother but no mother-father relationship. The goal is to have a 'normalized' relationship view, hence every related person should only appear once.

Answer (score 0):

Nice riddle, if in the table everyone are related then solution is quite easy:

```
SELECT t1.USER_ID, t1.RELATED_PERSON FROM table t1 HAVING t1.USERID = MIN(t1.USERID)
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned in comments above case required some additional assumptions. Here is my try that using correlated subqueries ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10a12/8/0)):

```
SELECT f.USER_ID, f.RELATED_PERSON FROM family f
WHERE 
  f.USER_ID NOT IN 
  ( 
    SELECT USER_ID FROM family WHERE USER_ID > f.USER_ID AND RELATED_PERSON > f.RELATED_PERSON 
    UNION 
    SELECT RELATED_PERSON FROM family WHERE USER_ID > f.USER_ID AND RELATED_PERSON > f.RELATED_PERSON  
  )
  AND
  f.RELATED_PERSON NOT IN 
  ( 
    SELECT USER_ID FROM family WHERE USER_ID > f.USER_ID AND RELATED_PERSON > f.RELATED_PERSON 
    UNION 
    SELECT RELATED_PERSON FROM family WHERE USER_ID > f.USER_ID AND RELATED_PERSON > f.RELATED_PERSON  
  )
```

But the case with more than one unrelated families is still a question. GL! Keep us posted.

Comment: Every family member relationship is in the table but only in one direction, hence there is a father-mother but no mother-father relationship. Your solution depends on that the father has the smallest userid, but we cannot rely on that (it might be that e.g. the mother or child has a smaller id than the father)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but you compare user id's which each other. This is unfortunately not possible in my case since not reliable. The family member type can be used though ('01' is always the father). I tried rewriting your query using the family member type as comparison condition but it didn't work for me.

Comment: There was some small error above, now it's corrected. Look into SQLFiddle link. It isn't taking into constideration the family member type, but returns some minimal set that connects whole familly. If something is wrong, keep me posted!

Comment: Hi Wawrzyniec,thanks a lot for all your efforts! And also the hint about SQLFiddle. This is really great :-)! Unfortunately the query still does not return the result I need and as it seems really tricky achieving this with plain SQL, I decided using an additional technology to parse the SQL output and do whatever I need. Thanks again!